# How to use nuxtjs/auth-next module with Nuxt3?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt-module

Just trying to add authentication to my NuxtJs 3 app folloging `nuxt/auth` [configuration docs](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup#installation),  but still get an error during app start:

[image]

```js
// nuxt.config.js

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    auth: {
        // ...
    },
    modules: [
        // '@nuxtjs/axios',
        '@nuxtjs/auth-next'
    ],
})
```

Received same error for `@nuxtjs/axios` but I just commented it out since its official [documentation](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/) indicates to switch to [`$fetch API`](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/data-fetching/#usefetch).

Cannot figure out where the error is

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`nuxt-auth`](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module) is not compatible with Nuxt3 as told here: https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/1805#issuecomment-1326287711

It's on the [official roadmap](https://nuxt.com/docs/community/roadmap#%EF%B8%8F-roadmap) but still not done by the core team.

You could google for a homemade solution online.  Thanks to Nuxt3 composables and some logic, it is totally achievable without an official module.

---

You can use [that community one](https://github.com/sidebase/nuxt-auth) in the meantime, as [confirmed here](https://twitter.com/TheAlexLichter/status/1600933215405019173).

Comment: Thanks, totally missed it, kinda feel stupid now

Comment: @fudo all good, no shame. Happens to everybody.

Answer (score 3):

At the time being, `nuxt/auth` module is not supported by Nuxt3.

You can find the list of modules supported by Nuxt3 here https://nuxt.com/modules?version=3.x

Answer (score 1):

You can use this nuxt-auth module which is compatible with nuxt 3: https://nuxt.com/modules/nuxt-auth https://github.com/sidebase/nuxt-auth

Comment: Third party maintainer but it's indeed a viable solution in the meantime.